# Camera Calibration Issue with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

After Calibrating with 15 Images I get a camera matrix and the distortion coefficients. The problem is that when distorting the image according to the camera parameters I get a strange circle shaped distortion:
[Distorted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcVlV.jpg)

On the first glance, can anybody say what went wrong during calibration?

Thank you.

Comment: also, what are typical camera matrix and distortion coefficient values, as they seem far to high in my case.

Comment: can you add the used input images?

Comment: I fixed it, mixed up the distortion coefficients, my bad.